# button click event is not firing in a pop up window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a website in asp.Net which contains a pop up with a asp button. my problem is that button click event is not firing in pop up. my pop opens when imagebutton1 clicks. i am also using timer tick in that. 
i am totally stucked in it. 
my code is as follows:-

```
 <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function buttonClicked() {
      var textBox = $get("TextBox1");
      textBox.scrollTop = textBox.scrollHeight;
         }

      </script>

      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ChatUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                               <ContentTemplate>

      <div id="second1" runat="server" style="width:570px;height:100px;background-color:#e5f7f6;border:solid 2px #35b8b3;position:absolute;margin-left:5px;margin-top:5px;border-radius:5px;">
      <span style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold;margin-left:180px;margin-top:20px;">Ringing Expert...Please Wait</span>

 </div>                 
               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" 
                                    width="100%" style="resize:none;" Height="200px" AutoPostBack="False" 
                    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True" >
                    </asp:TextBox>

            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SendButton" EventName="Click" />--%>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ChatTextTimer" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
              <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="ChatTextTimer" Interval="100" 
                    ontick="ChatTextTimer_Tick" />

                    <asp:TextBox ID="NewMessageTextBox" DefaultButton="SendButton" Columns="50" runat="server" Height="25px" 
            Width="80%" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-top:5px;" Font-Size="Medium" />
                    <asp:Button ID="SendButton" Text="Send" runat="server" OnClick="SendButton_Click" Height="25px" style="margin-left:50px;" />
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:line;">Report Abuse</a>
                    <br />
                    <div style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Width="70px" Height="50px" />
                            <div style="width:80%;height:50px;float:right;margin-right:30px;">
                                    Status:<br />
                                    <span style="color:Blue;font-weight:bold;font-size:large;">Not Charging</span>
                                    <span style="float:right;font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;color:Blue;">$ <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;color:Blue;" Text="Label"></asp:Label> / Minute</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

and my back end code is as follows:-

```
            protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    second1.Visible = false;
    if (Session["User"] != "User")
    {
        Response.Redirect("signin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Int32.Parse(Label13.Text) < 20)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Payment.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            if(Int32.Parse(Label14.Text)==0)
            {
               Response.Redirect("ExpertMail.aspx?id="+Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]));
            }
            else
            {
                string str1 = Label1.Text;
                string str = "<script type='text/javascript'>$(function (){ $('#modal_dialog').dialog({title: 'Chat with Expert', modal: true }); return false; });</script>";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Script", str, false);
                Image3.ImageUrl = Label8.Text;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LPSConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd = new SqlCommand("Select Booked from ExpertChat where id=" + Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]), con).ExecuteReader();
            rd.Read();
            int y = Int32.Parse(rd["Booked"].ToString());
            rd.Close();
            if (y == 0)
            {

                SqlDataReader mRead1, mRead3,mRead4;
                mRead1 = new SqlCommand("insert into chat (ExpertName,UserName,rate) Values ('" + Label1.Text + "','" + Session["SName"] + "','" + Label5.Text + "')", con).ExecuteReader();
                mRead1.Close();
                mRead3 = new SqlCommand("Update ExpertChat Set Booked=1 where SName='" + Label1.Text + "'", con).ExecuteReader();
                mRead3.Close();
                second1.Visible = true;
                con.Close();

            }
            con.Close();

            }
        }
    }

}
public void wait(int x)
{

}
protected void ChatTextTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (second1.Visible)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LPSConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader mRead4 = new SqlCommand("Select top 1 id from Chat where ExpertName='" + Label1.Text + "' order by id desc", con).ExecuteReader();
        mRead4.Read();
        int z = Int32.Parse(mRead4["id"].ToString());
        mRead4.Close();

        SqlDataReader rd = new SqlCommand("Select IsApproved from Chat where id=" + z, con).ExecuteReader();
        rd.Read();
        string str = (rd["IsApproved"].ToString());
        rd.Close();
        if (str == "Approved")
        {
            second1.Visible = false;

        }
        else if (str == "canceled")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();

        }

    }
    else
    {
        int x1 = 0;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LPSConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd;
        rd = new SqlCommand("Select UserInitial,Updated from Chat where id =" + Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()), con).ExecuteReader();
        rd.Read();
        string str;
        int i;
        str = rd["UserInitial"].ToString();
        i = Int32.Parse(rd["Updated"].ToString());
        rd.Close();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            x1 = x1 + 1;
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + str;
            SqlCommand
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Chat set Updated=0 where id=" + Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()), con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "TextBox1slide", "buttonClicked();", true);
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LPSConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString());
    //con.Open();
    string messageMask = "{0} : {2}";
    string message = string.Format(messageMask, Session["SName"].ToString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), NewMessageTextBox.Text);
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + message;
    //SqlCommand cmd, cmd1;
    //cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Chat set Data='" + message + "' where id=" + Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()), con);
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Update Chat set Updated1=1 where id=" + Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()), con);
    //cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    NewMessageTextBox.Text = "";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "myScript", "document.getElementById('" + NewMessageTextBox.ClientID + "').value = '';", true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "TextBox1slide", "buttonClicked();", true);



}
```

Comment: Which button's event is not firing? And do you refer to your javascript function `buttonClicked` not being called, or did you mean the asp.net code-behind `button_Click` event?

Comment: button id is SendButton and this button must fire an event in back end code. this is server side code actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved it .
it was a silly mistake. just set your button's SubMitBehaviour Property to false...